# Average rating using two views in Entity Framework & ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have created two models, see below. Used entity framework scaffolding to create controller and views.

In create review page the option is given to enter a review of `int`.

In my `Healthprofessional` index view however I would like to send the average rating given to each health professional.

I have tried `foreach` statement in **healthprofessional** razor view however only one model can be referenced in each view in razor which makes this difficult for me.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.HealthReviews)
{
    // get error for this foreach when I try to apply
    // as item.Rating does not contain  
    // a public definition for getenumerator
    foreach (var rating in item.Rating)
    { }
}
```

I'm thinking applying linq to controller may be answer but I've spent hours at this stage trying to do it and not too familiar with linq.

Any suggestions on how to move forward with this problem I would greatly appreciate.

```
public enum Profession { Counsellor, Physio, Doctor }

public class HealthProfessional
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool AcceptsMedicalCard { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(80)]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Profession Profession { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Review> HealthReviews { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class Review
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ClientID { get; set; }
    public int? HealthProfessionalID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5, ErrorMessage = "Please select number between 1 and 5")]
    public int Rating { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ReviewText { get; set; }
    public bool WouldRecommend { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public HealthProfessional HealthProfessional { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Comment in first piece of code should read: I get error for this foreach loop of item.rating as I am prompted that 
 item.Rating does not contain  a public definition for getenumerator

Comment: The problem lies with your logic. The `item.Rating` in your 2nd `foreach` is of data type `int`, so you cannot be looping over it. Instead, you calculate the average rating from the collection of reviews by aggregating the sum of the rating of each review and then dividing it by the total number of reviews.

Comment: True, but i'd need to access the ratings property from the Review model to use in the healthprofessional view. And the average rating needs to be based off each individual healthcare professional. If you could provide an example i'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already looping over `HealthReviews` which is an `ICollection<Review>`, and each `Review` contains an `int Rating`. It makes no sense to try looping over that, it is a single value already that you can use directly.

You code will need to look something like this:

```
@{
    int sumOfRatings = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model.HealthReviews)
    {
        sumOfRatings += item.Rating;
        // ...
    }

    double averageRating = Model.HealthReviews.Count > 0
        ? (double)sumOfRatings / Model.HealthReviews.Count
        : 0;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, one last thing if you don't mind. If another rather view has model IEnumerable<CareCompProj.Models.HealthProfessional> at beginning rather than @model CareCompProj.Models.HealthProfessional Could this method still be applied? It works on the latter but because the other view already iterates through the list of Health professionals i'm not sure

Comment: Yes, you'd just have an outer loop for the `IEnumerable<HealthProfessional>` and then an inner loop on `professional.HealthReviews` (which is an `ICollection<Review>`).

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code below but getting NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "foreach (var r in p.HealthReviews)" is highlighted as the issue when I click on the page

Comment: @{
        int sumOfRatings = 0;
        foreach (var p in Model)
        {
            foreach (var r in p.HealthReviews)
            {
                sumOfRatings += r.Rating;
                // ...
            }
            double averageRating = p.HealthReviews.Count > 0
                ? (double)sumOfRatings / p.HealthReviews.Count
                : 0;

                <p> @averageRating </p>
            }
          }

Comment: You'd better ask a new question if the problem persists, comments are not for follow up questions

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method in `HealthProfessional` class to calculate the average rating.

```
public class HealthProfessional
{
    public ICollection<Review> HealthReviews { get; set; }

    public double CalculateAverageRating()
    {
        return HealthReviews.Average(r => r.Rating);
    }
}
```

Then, you call the method in your Controller action method and assign it to a property of your view model.

Comment: Thank you for your help, appreciate it

Comment: For the above, Where(r => r.id) I get an error stating "cannot implicitly convert int to bool"

Comment: @Drew88 Sorry, that was a mistake, which I have corrected already.

Comment: No worries, thanks. I'm getting ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
System.Linq.Enumerable.Average<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> selector) when tried this when going to health professional page the code applied above is highlighted.

Comment: I have corrected my answer. You should be calling the method to calculate the average in your Controller action method, then assign it to a property of your view model, which is to be passed to your view.